# Combine and convert nvarchar month field + float year field to a single date field

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, datetime

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 with a month column stored as `nvarchar(255)`:

```
"January", "February", "March"
```

And another column in this table with year stored separately as float

```
"2012","2013,"2014".
```

I do not have a day column so I want to create a combined month date column with the day starting as 1.

So for month and year fields January 2012. I want to show '2012-01-01'

How can I do such and add that into my current table?

I want to find the maximum row for a record in my table for each employee.
so for an [employee #], [month],[year]. what is latest record so for example below:

```
1. 102, Jan, 2019
2. 102, feb, 2019
```

I want to only see the second record which is the latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server has pretty flexible conversion to date.  So, just convert the columns to a date:

```
select convert(date, month + ' ' + year)
```

You can get the maximum as:

```
select empid, max(convert(date, month + ' ' + year))
from t
group by empid;
```

If you really like, you can change the format for output purposes.  I would advise you to stick with a `date`, though.

Note:  This assumes that your internationalization settings are set to English -- which seems reasonable if you are storing month names in English.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your design! The way you store data makes it really inefficient to interpret it. Here, I think the simplest option is `datefromparts()` and a 12-branches `case` expression.

Assuming that the (float) year is stored in column `col_year` and the (string) month is in `col_month`:

```
select t.*,
    datefromparts(
        cast(col_year as int),
        case col_month
            when 'January'  then  1
            when 'February' then  2
            ...
            when 'December' then 12
        end,
        1
    ) as date_col
from mytable t
```

Comment: thanks i agree. the data is uploaded from excel and comes in this format so i want to fix the design to get the data stored properly